# how to pass file in angularjs using submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

```
<div class="divMainContainer" ng-controller="loginController">
            <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginChecks($files)">
               <table class="imagetable">
                    <tr>                          
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="color:red;"> {{oneMore.firstName}}</td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Enter login detail</th>                            
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtUserName" ng-model="data.txtName" required></td>                                
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" ng-model="data.txtPassword" required> </td>     
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>File upload data</td>
                        <td><input type="file"> </td>     
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                          
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
                    </tr>                         
                </table>  
            </form>             
        </div>
```

In the above code. how can i upload the file upload when user press submit button.. it should not uploaded when the file is selected.

Comment: You can get this on server side

Comment: It's browser specific and FileApi, I don't see task for AngularJS, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use directives like: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload, which will provide handle to the file on the client side, the example also provide syntax for server side api call

Comment: Yes right. i had already used it. but There is no document for how to upload file when the submit button changed. It works when i just select the file at that time it call the onFileSelect() function.